# What's the best survival strategy for Running With the Bulls?

Tags: safety, health, spain

The Running of the Bulls can be quite dangerous, obviously.

[image: Ouch!]

As you're running in a narrow street, with hundreds of other inept runners, what's the best strategy for running the route with the bulls, without loss of respect (for example, hiding under a staircase is not a valid strategy).

Comment: Run faster than the guy behind you.

Comment: Well full respect to the guy in the photo even though he's a bit stupid. Full respect also to the bull who was pretty smart.

Comment: This picture looks horrible, but I think the guy can be happy that the bull only hit his foot and not something else.

Comment: @Roflcoptr: It seems the bull also at least lightly scraped his shin too.

Comment: You might also consider [ethical issues](http://www.peta.org.au/news/running-of-the-bulls-is-for-bullies/) of this venue. The best survival strategy for everyone involved would be not to run at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran at San Fermin in 2007. It is among the scariest things I have done, but quite an experience.

There is a double bend early in the course where it goes through a large plaza. Our plan was to start before that plaza, run to that, so that we could hop out if we needed to. Since it is unpredictable I would recommend planning something like that. Get a map of the route the day before, and plan out some good places to hop out if it seems you're about to be trampled.

You want to plan because it will be crazy once the run starts, and if you aren't prepared, you may be in for trouble.

### Don't be stupid

It's a fun event, and it seems that just about everyone has stayed up all night drinking and now wants to share the street with some confused and enormous bulls that have no traction. If you want to party, do it every other night except the one before you run. You have to be there so early anyways (I believe we woke up around 4:30AM to get there on time).

### Don't run WITH them

Find a way to get behind the bulls and follow them to the arena. Out of our group of about 5-6 people, two of us hopped out and stayed behind, the rest were able to safely avoid the bulls and follow them into the arena. When you see people get gored, they are running in front of, or right alongside the bulls.

### In the arena at the end, just watch

Once the bulls get to the bullfight arena, everyone that comes in is antagonizing and "fighting" the bulls, as if they were matadors. You'll have plenty to watch without injuring yourself.

You can have plenty of fun without endangering your life. Assuming you don't live there and will be making a trip for it, there's no reason to be maimed for a little excitement to prove how daring you can be.

Comment: Hey, I was there in 2007 as well! Friday the 13th of July.  Sadly was dragged off the course by the *policia* for carrying a camera.  Ran into a shop, thrust the camera at them and ran back, but they don't let you on the course with 5 min to go :/

Comment: Nice! We were there on the 13th but only ran on the 14th. Did you not get another chance?

Comment: Sadly no, we were out at the campsite 25ish km away, and although I wanted to go back the next day, the others I was with ended up having a big drinking night and it didn't happen.  Maybe I'll return one day tho :/

Comment: Better go before you end up valuing your safety too much.. :)